# Retrieve code after external provider API login using ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am writing a code that directs users to an external API provider webpage where they will enter their login details  and then return the code the end of the redirect url.
The code below does not work. It does not even redirect to the authorisation url.

I'm using Oauth2.0 and doing this in c# asp.netcore. Thank you in advance

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetCode()
        
    {
            vurl = Provider.GetUrl();
            //redirect user to url   
            return Redirect(vurl);
            //read and extract code from url      
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:8000/");

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json"));

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            string resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                               
    }
```

PS: the question has been edited with updated code

Comment: The user will be *redirected* back to your site. Resulting in a completely separate http request.

Comment: Thanks. Pls see the updated code. it still doesn't work. I would appreciate an advise on how to make this work. Thank you

Comment: OAuth is not one request, it's a sequence of requests.

Comment: I do understand that. The first step will be to redirect the user to the external login so they can enter their credentials - to return an authorisation code.  I've used  'return redirect' in my code. But this does not work. What am I going wrong?